# Как создать экземпляр класса имея переменную типа Class

Tags: java

Есть переменная

```
private Class clazz = Some.class;
```

Как создать из этой переменной

```
new Some();
```

Пока дошел до этого:

```
Object object = clazz.newInstance();
```

Дело в том что не известно какой тип будет получен

```
    public class GsonRequest<ResponseObject> extends Request<ResponseObject>
    {
        private final Gson gson = new Gson();
        private Class clazz;
        private final Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        private final Listener<ResponseObject> listener;
        private ApiEnum ae;
        private Object object;
        /**
         * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
         *
         * @param url URL of the request to make
         * @param clazz Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
         * @param headers Map of request headers
         */
        public GsonRequest(String url, ApiEnum ae,
        Class clazz, Listener<ResponseObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener)
        {
            super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
            this.listener = listener;
            this.ae = ae;
            this.clazz = clazz;
            /*switch (ae)
            {
                case SESSION:
                    this.clazz = SessionRequest.class;
                    break;
                case CATEGORIES:
                    this.clazz = Categories.class;
                    break;
            }*/
            try
            {
                object = clazz.newInstance();
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e)
            {}
            catch (InstantiationException e)
            {}
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
        {
            headers.put("Id", "123");
            return headers; 
        }

        @Override
        protected void deliverResponse(ResponseObject response)
        {
            listener.onResponse(response);
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<ResponseObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) 
        {
            try
            {
                String json = new String(
                    response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));

                object = gson.fromJson(json, clazz);
                ResponseObject r = (ResponseObject) new BaseResponse().setAnswer(object);
// В ResponseObject метод setAnswer не вызывается
                return Response.success(
                    r,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
            {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            }
            catch (JsonSyntaxException e)
            {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            }
        }
    }
```

ResponsiObject:

```
public class ResponseObject
{
    @Nullable private Object mAnswer;

    private RequestResult mRequestResult;

    public ResponseObject() {
        mRequestResult = RequestResult.ERROR;
    }

    @NonNull
    public RequestResult getRequestResult() {
        return mRequestResult;
    }

    public ResponseObject setRequestResult(RequestResult requestResult) {
        mRequestResult = requestResult;
        return this;
    }

    @Nullable
    public <T> T getTypedAnswer() {
        if (mAnswer == null) {
            return null;
        }
        //noinspection unchecked
        return (T) mAnswer;
    }

    public ResponseObject setAnswer(@Nullable Object answer) {
        mAnswer = answer;
        return this;
    }

    public void save(Context context) {
    }
}
```

Base Response:

```
public class BaseResponse extends ResponseObject {

}
```

Activity:

```
private Response.Listener<ResponseObject> myReqSuccessListener()
    {
        return new Response.Listener<ResponseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ResponseObject response)
            {
                if (response.getTypedAnswer() instanceof SessionRequest)
                {
                    SessionRequest session = response.getTypedAnswer();
                    //...
                }
                else if (response.getTypedAnswer() instanceof Categories)
                {
                    Categories categories = response.getTypedAnswer();


            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Э-э-э... `Some some = (Some) clazz.newInstance();` ???

Comment: Типов, как я понимаю, будет ограниченное кол-во, а значит вы можете сделать switch по типам и в нём кастовать полученный объект к конкретномму типу.

Comment: Вариант который я использую работает, я просто хочу знать как делается правильно.

Comment: На самом деле правильный ответ зависит о того, для чего нужен Вам этот Object object. Если просто чтобы был и пофиг какого класса, то всё правильно и так. this.clazz явно лишний.

Comment: Я делаю запрос с помощью volley, Class class это модель json который я получаю, их несколько

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Object o;
Class clazz;

switch (ae)
{
    case SESSION:
        clazz = SessionRequest.class;
        break;
    case CATEGORIES:
        clazz = Categories.class;
        break;
}

if(clazz == null)
{
    log.error("class {} not found!", clazz.getName());
    return;
}

try
{
    o = clazz.newInstance();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    log.error("Failed creating instance of {}", e, clazz.getName());
    return;
}
```

И не нужно забивать лишними параметрами конструктор - сами себе же усложняете инициальзацию.